# How to add pan zoom button in graph generated using cytoscape.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cytoscape.js

I am using [cytoscape.js](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/) to create & display graph. Now, I want to add pan & zoom buttons, so that user can zoom and pan very large graph. I have found a plug-in cytoscape-panzoom included with [cytoscape.js](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/). I have include all required files in my page :-

e.g.

- jquery.cytoscape-panzoom.js,
- jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js,
- jquery.cytoscape-panzoom.css

But no pan zoom buttons are shown. How can i solve this problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the jQuery plugin (panzoom) as normal for a jQuery plugin on the cytoscape.js div:

```
$('#some-cy-div').cytoscapePanzoom({ /* options... */ });
```

Comment: I have called **$('#cy').cytoscapePanzoom();** inside **<script>** tag and also modified path to images in **jquery.cytoscape-panzoom.css** file as **.ui-cytoscape-panzoom-zoom-button .ui-icon { background-image: url("Images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png"); .ui-cytoscape-panzoom-static .ui-cytoscape-panzoom-zoom-button .ui-icon { background-image: url("Images/ui-icons_000000_256x240.png");**, but still same problem occurs.